# How to use old variable value in callback function (the one at the time of defining the callback) instead of value at callback runtime?

Tags: objective-c, ios, callback

Let's see this example:

```
int a = 1;
[someOperation onCompletion:^(...) {
     NSLog("%d", a);
}];

a = 2;
```

Let's say `someOperation` took 1 second to finish.
So there would be "2" on console.

How to define callback body with variable values from the time of defining the callback (so that in this case callback execution would print "1" on console) ?

In JavaScript it could be done as follows:

```
setTimeout("someFunction("+variable+")", 1000);
```

instead of

```
setTimeout(function() { someFunction(variable); }, 1000);
```

But how to accomplish this thing in ObjC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is not correct.
A block copies local variables unless they are declared with the __block keyword.
So, in your case:

```
int a = 1;
[someOperation onCompletion:^(...) {
     NSLog(@"%i", a);
}];

a = 2;
```

NSLog statement would return 1.
If you change it like this:

```
int __block a = 1;
[someOperation onCompletion:^(...) {
     NSLog(@"%i", a);
}];

a = 2;
```

it would return 2, because in this case a is accessed by reference

Comment: It appears to be right. I must have made some logicall mistake before because I really thought it does not work that way. Thanks for clearing my wrong impression and for the tip about __block - I didn't know about this

Answer (score 1):

if you try

```
int a = 1;
int64_t delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    NSLog(@"a=%d", a);
});
a = 2;
```

you will be delighted to find that the answer is

```
a=1
```

Because the standard behaviour of blocks is to capture the values of the variables they reference when they are created, and then use those stored values when they run. I'm sure there's a cleverer way of saying that, but that's how it works for me.

Comment: It appears to be right. I must have made some logicall mistake before because I really thought it does not work that way. Thanks for clearing my wrong impression